# Python3 - Store stdout into an array variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdftotext

I have a Python script, that converts PDF content to a string.

```
text = list();

#npages is number of pages in the PDF file.
for n in range(npages):
    text[n] = os.system('pdftotext myfile.pdf -') #the "-" prints to stdout.

print(text)
```

However when I print `text`, this is the output (a PDF file with two pages):

```
{0: 0, 1: 0}
```

When running the script, I see the `os.system` output being sent to the command line:

```
text from myfile.pdf page 1
text from myfile.pdf page 2
```

How can I store the standard output from the `pdftotext` command in a list?

Comment: But you create a dictionary at line 1? Is it list or dictionary?

Comment: @Wimanicesir Ah sorry - fixed!

Comment: ① if `text` were a _list_, you will receive an `IndexError` when you try to access the non-existing element `text[0]` ② at every iteration you are receiving the whole text of the PDF file, not just the text of an individual page.  Very sloppy question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not receiving command line outputs, only the returned system code. Generally 0 is for success, which means your commands for `npages` 0 and 1 were successful.

You may use `subprocess` and redirect output to your Python script. A shorthand for this is:

```
import subprocess

out = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-lh']) # example
print(out)
```

---

To accept the short `-` you'll need to use `subprocess.Popen(bufsize=0)`. This should work:

```
cmd = ['pdftotext', 'myfile.pdf', '-']
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)
# get output and error
out, err = proc.communicate()

print(out)
```

Comment: I am a little confused on how/where to use the `subprocess` for `pdftotext` call. If I do: `text[n] = subprocess.check_output('pdftotext myfile.pdf -)` I get the following error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or director: 'pdftotext myfile.pdf -'`

Comment: @oliverbj check doc first, before you ask! It should be `subprocess.check_output(['pdftotext', 'myfile.pdf', '-'])` which only accepts commands in a list.

Comment: @oliverbj In the answer the argument to `check_output` is a _list_ of strings, in your comment it is a _string_.  Maybe is this difference the reason way of your erros?

Comment: @oliverbj Looks like it's caused by the last `-`. You'll need `subprocess.Popen` for that. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @knh190 - I just tried doing `subprocess.check_output(['pdftotext', 'myfile.pdf', '-'])` - but that returns with an `error code of 99`. I also tried removing the `-` part.

Comment: @oliverbj code 99 is program specific error code. Check the `err` message using updated answer.